# Save as a .txt file CMD/powershell outputs

Tags: powershell, cmd

I write a command like `tree` and all outputs printed on the console.
I wanna save the printed outputs as a `.txt` file, the file path is gonna set the target terminal path.

How can I do that?

Comment: `tree >> myfile.txt`

Comment: @notjustme thank you, How can I do that on CMD?

Comment: What do you mean? That line is what you need for cmd (but it works in PowerShell as well).

Comment: use `>>` only if you wish to append the output to a file that contains output from previous executions. If you only require the output from the current instance, use `>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line does what you are asking for. It should work both in CMD and PowerShell.

```
tree >> myfile.txt
```